# Odd "bug/user error" in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have this line of HTML

```
<input id="checkVSC" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" name="checkVSC" 
data-onstyle="info" data-offstyle="default" data-size="small" 
data-on="<i class='icon icon-checkmark'></i> VSC" 
data-off="<i class='icon icon-line-plus'></i> VSC">
```

for the data-on it gives me the green squiggly line saying: `"If the attribute value is enclosed in quotations marks, the quotation marks must match"`

This isn't a major item, but when I do Ctrl-K Ctrl-D to re-format the lines of code to make them neat and pretty it adds a `">"` to the data-on attribute.

```
<input id="checkVSC" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" name="checkVSC" 
data-onstyle="info" data-offstyle="default" data-size="small" 
**data-on="><i class='icon icon-checkmark'></i> VSC"** 
data-off="<i class='icon icon-line-plus'></i> VSC">
```

Any one have any idea as to what is going on here and why it is doing what it is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS gets fooled because your HTML is invalid.

Attribute strings should be escaped:

```
data-on="&lt;i class='icon icon-checkmark'&gt;&lt;/i&gt; VSC" 
data-off="&lt;i class='icon icon-line-plus'&gt;&lt;/i&gt; VSC">
```

To avoid such situations in the future You might try to:

- [enable HTML validation](http://www.kodyaz.com/visual-studio/html-validation-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx)
- try any online validator

Some other IDEs and text editors provide automatic validation and even automatic escaping as well.

Comment: I didn't even think of that, thank you, it is working perfectly now.